# Laravel authentication for API

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm making an app which consists of react-based SPA frontend and RESTful api made with laravel on backend.
I need an authentication for api.
I cant use default laravel authentication because it uses cookies and I don't wanna use cookies because later the api is gonna be used also by mobile app.
I cant use laravel passport because, well, it's aimed for third-party users of api and my api ain't goona be used by other applications.
Are there any other solutions?

Comment: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin great suggestion.

Comment: You can also use laravel's passport

Comment: I don't wanna use laravel passport because oauth is needed for third-party users and my api gonna be used only by me, also it is not very easy to customize passport.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is hosted in the same domain or sub domain as your backend then checkout [Laravel Airlock](https://laravel.com/docs/master/airlock)

It should support both SPA apps and Mobiles apps using secure http cookies and api tokens

Alternatively you can still use oAuth with Passport and go for either PKCE Token grant or Password grant. In both cases you might consider using a proxy backend to secure client_secret and the access_token which can be done through use of http cookies and csrf protection - similar to what Laravel Airlock does

Comment: Hi, Laravel Airlock has been renamed to Laravel Sanctum.  https://laravel-news.com/laravel-airlock-renamed-to-sanctum